# ASWebAuthenticationSession/Azure AD B2C - Error: The provided scheme is not valid. A scheme > should not include special characters such as ":" or "/"

Tags: swiftui, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I am getting this error:

> [AuthenticationSession] The provided scheme is not valid. A scheme
> should not include special characters such as ":" or "/".

When trying to use ASWebAuthenticationSession for a SwiftUI project:

```
    let authURL = URL(string: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
    let scheme = "msauth.com.xxxxxxx.Test1://auth"

    self.session = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(url: authURL!, callbackURLScheme: scheme, completionHandler: { callbackURL, error in
        guard error == nil, let successURL = callbackURL else {
            return
        }

        let oauthToken = URLComponents(string: (successURL.absoluteString))?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first

        print(oauthToken ?? "No OAuth Token")
    })
```

The oAuth provider is Azure AD B2C where I have configured a mobile app for iOS / macOS.

I have followed these examples for:

- [Using ASWebAuthenticationSession with SwiftUI](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/using-aswebauthenticationaession-swiftui/)
- [ASWebAuthenticationSession for Web Login in iOS App](https://devgenes.com/posts/ASWebAuthenticationSession-for-Web-Login-in-iOS-App/)

I have stayed away from the MSAL sample in GitHub because there is no [SwiftUI example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal/issues/47) and the issue has been outstanding for a year.

Maybe I should choose a different option for AuthenticationServices:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t recommend this approach since you have no token caching etc. The doc you linked says `The scheme has to be everything up to but not including :// of your URL.`. So do exactly that. You are better off integrating the [MSAL lines](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal/blob/master/MSALiOSB2C/ViewController.swift) into your code, should be copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks, @JasSuri-MSFT. In the first link they use "fairese-nae://anilist-auth" and the second uses "aswebauthdemo://auth" for the redirect URI, so I am trying to reconcile the discrepancy. I was caught between using MSAL and taking the native platform oAuth implementation route. I probably would have stayed with MSAL (I did with Android) except there was only a UIKit example and the request to create a SwiftUI one assigned a year ago but there was no further communication on it. I see so many Firebase ones, which use their own package as well. I would use MSAL but it uses UIViewController.

Comment: Rob codes around the issue with this project https://github.com/arbyruns/SwiftUI-MSALSample. I guess I was just nervous about developer support for MSAL given SwiftUI is a significant platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by encoding the url before passing it to the session.

```
scheme.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution for this.

```
 let scheme = Url(string: "msauth.com.xxxxxxx.Test1://auth").Scheme ?? ""
```